# Angular 5: await promise in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have following component with a `ngOnInit` function:

```js
declare var ThirdPartyObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html'
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  public test: any;
  public imageExporter: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let thiz = this;
    ThirdPartyObject.getPackage("test").then(function (testNameSpace) {
      testNameSpace.onReady(function () {
        thiz.test = testNameSpace;
        thiz.imageExporter = new thiz.test.ImageExporter("args");
      });
    }, function (error) {
      setTimeout(function () { thiz.ngOnInit(); }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

How do I wait for the `imageExporter` value to be defined before the `templateUrl` of this component is loaded?

Comment: where is `templateUrl` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `resolver` , in your routing you can define what should happen before going to that route

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

ps. if you using arrow functions you don't need to use `thiz` for exmaple

```
ThirdPartyObject.getPackage("test").then((testNameSpace) => {
    testNameSpace.onReady(() => {
      this.test = testNameSpace;
      this.imageExporter = new this.test.ImageExporter("args");
    });
  }
```